# Accessing User Application from Web Application

Tags: asp.net, web-applications

I have a dll i created that gets the excel object on users computer(if excel is installed) and has a handful of availalbe functions. I made a reverence to the dll in a Web Application. When I test this using the local host it works. If I deploy this on a Web Server will it still work or will it try to find the excel application on the server?

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing  your code I can only offer a guess, and my guess is that it will search the server and not the users computer.

You can probably use ActiveX to call Excel from the users computer, but that would only work in IE.  I'm not sure who your audience is, but I needed similar functionality for the company I used to work for.  For that I made a program that was installed to all users computers and then we used a custom http protocol that would open up programs on the client machine through a hyperlink.  Doing it this way is cross browser compatible.

Comment: Actually I would like to acces the clients cad station (solidworks). So basically the client would have to download the .dll onto their machine, then the web application would have to make calls to it to send and recieve data. Do you have an example? I have been a Windows App programmer for 4 years and just getting started with Web App. Thanks. ps i would comment but since i had to make a new account it won't let me.

Comment: I don't think it is possible to interact with a .dll on the client machine directly because of security.  You could create a small console app that runs on the client machine that can talk between the machine and your web app.  I don't have an example but this link might get you started: [link]http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767914(VS.85).aspx